# Best way to show the meaning of a score in a chart?

Tags: website-design, charts

I have charts that display calculated progress.
What I want to be able to do, is given a result, show whether that score falls in the  Average,Above Average,Below Average or Excellent.
What would be the best way to do this ? 
Charts take values 1-10.

1-2 is Below Average

3-5-Average

4-7- Above Average

7-10- Excellent

Do I put the chart color in a different intensitiy, lighter being below average and with full intensity being Excellent ?
This is what it looks like now : [image]

Every chart gets filled a color depending on the number.
But what would be the best way to give the numbers a meaning ?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Even if you use colour to signify the score, is that explained somewhere to the users?

Have you considered simply adding text under each score explaining what you are trying to convey or include a legend that indicates what the scores mean?

Sometimes the simplest solution is the best one. Just tell your users what you are trying to show them.

Answer (score 0):

You can use donut charts to display the given information in segments. Google donut chart is a good example of how your data can be visualized.

[image: Google Donut Chart]

You can follow the link for more information [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#donut)